# Как установить значение переменной по умолчанию используя hibernate анотации?

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, связывание-данных

Как установить значение по умолчанию для переменной `entity-класса` используя `hibernate-анотации`?

Я просто установил значение для переменной `status`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id_user;
    private String nickname;
    private String status= "User";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110266/how-to-set-default-value-in-hibernate

Comment: Вы уверены? Насколько я понимаю, данный способ просто описывает 
состояние поля в БД, но не устанавливает значение переменной.

Comment: Установить значение переменной - вот же у вас пример: private String status= "User";
Или такой вариант не компилируется с аннотацией?

Comment: Да, так работает, но я хотел бы узнать как это сделать именно с помощью анотации hibernate.

Comment: В документации не нашел значение по-умолчанию. Мне непонятно почему не сделали, вроде ж делается просто.
Подождем ответа более осведомленных людей :)

Comment: Просто слышал что есть такой способ, и хотель узнать как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пообщавшись с [*MaxXx1313*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/842/maxxx1313) я пришол к выводу, что с помощью `hibernate-анотации` установить значение переменной по умолчанию не получится. Можно это сделать другими способаси, но все это слишком задротно и наверно не правильно для такой простой вещи))

Вобщем не заморачиваемся и по простом сами указываем значение переменной:
*private String status=* `"User"`;

Answer (score -2):

@ColumnDefault("User")

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]